# What does "coupling effects" mean in the context of optical systems?

Tags: optics, coupling

What does it mean to say that there are "coupling effects" between some elements of an optical system? I've searched through the literature, but I cannot find a general explanation of what this means – every mention of it assumes that the reader already knows what it means.

Comment: Does any of this help. [Coupling Effects in Optical Metamaterials](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/anie.200906211), [Coupling Effect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/coupling-effect), [-1- Coupling of Optical Lumped Nanocircuit Elements and Effects of Substrates](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0706/0706.1316.pdf), [Coupling characterization and noise studies of the optical metrology system onboard the LISA Pathfinder mission ](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-49-29-5665).

Comment: @Fred With regards to this https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/coupling-effect link, "Coupling effects are caused when the flux of a component is influenced by the driving force of another component due to thermodynamic (result of nonideality of the mixture inside the membrane) and kinetic coupling (result of interactions between the components and the membrane), which may result in concentration-dependent diffusion (Berendsen, Radmer, & Reuss, 2006;", I already read it, but I'm not totally sure that this description is relevant to the optical systems context. Feel free to clarify

Comment: @Fred After going through the other papers, none of them discuss coupling of the elements of an optical system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this paper](https://www.osapublishing.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-16-7-1730), as well as other sources I've come across in my research, it seems to just be a technical way of saying that the elements, or the action of the elements, "depend" on each other (have "dependancy" on the state of each other in some way).